# Python/Tkinter countdown not working

Tags: python, tkinter

It's just basically a label with a button that starts the timer from 30 to 0.

I don't know the reason why the .after(1000, temporizador) doesn't do his job, it just stays at 29, it's supposed to repeat the function until the counter reaches 0.

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
ventana = Tk()
v = StringVar()
v.set("30") 
def temporizador():
    counter = 29
    if counter <= 0:
        v.set("tiempo")
    else:
        v.set(str(counter))
        counter -= 1
        ventana.after(1000, temporizador)
etiqueta = Label(ventana, textvariable = v)
etiqueta.pack()
boton = Button(ventana, text="Empezar", command = temporizador)
boton.pack()
ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Nevermind i just found out the counter was just starting over on 29 everytime the function repeat itself, so i just create a global variable and  it works now

Comment: In this case, either provide an answer yourself or delete the question.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing the value assignation "counter = 29" at the beginning of your function, so every time the function "temporizador" is called (every second, I think), the value of the variable "counter" is going to be 29.

In order for this to work, you should:

1) Remove the value assignation to counter at the beginning of the function temporizador

2) Create another function that sets the value of counter to 29 and then calls temporizador, something like this:

```
def button_clicked():
    counter = 29
    temporizador()
```

3) Set the command of the button "boton" to be button_clicked instead of temporizador